# How to deal with clang's (3.9) -Wexpansion-to-defined warning?

Tags: c++, c, clang, undefined-behavior, defined

clang 3.9 has added to `-Wall` a the warning `-Wexpansion-to-defined`, which produces

> macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behaviour

in case `defined` is used outside an `#if` expression, including the case of a macro that is then used within an `#if` expression. For example the following code

```
// in some file:
#define HAS_GNU (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__))

// possibly in another file:
#if defined(__clang__) || HAS_GNU
/* ... */
#endif
```

produces

```
test.cc:5:27: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
#if defined(__clang__) || HAS_GNU
                          ^
test.cc:3:18: note: expanded from macro 'HAS_GNU'
#define HAS_GNU (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__))
                 ^
test.cc:5:27: warning: macro expansion producing 'defined' has undefined behavior [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
test.cc:3:40: note: expanded from macro 'HAS_GNU'
#define HAS_GNU (defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__))
```

So what's the 'correct' way to do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use #if - #else macros:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#define HAS_GNU 1
#else
#define HAS_GNU 0
#endif
```

Or, if you're willing to change the code that uses `HAS_GNU`, perhaps more conventional way:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#define HAS_GNU
#endif

#if defined(__clang__) || defined(HAS_GNU)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have this kind of problem with a 3d party pod, you may find this useful

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wexpansion-to-defined"
#import <pop/POP.h>
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. Question isn't about disabling the warnings.

Comment: The questions is "How to deal with...". If you have 3-rd library you obviously cannot make changes in source code. And this is how "How to deal with " this warning, especially if the project treats warning as errors